# Is there an industry standard for client side cryptography

Tags: javascript, cryptography

There are numerous articles on the web quoting the perils of JavaScript cryptography including this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195509/is-javascript-a-proper-platform-for-cryptography-or-can-it-be) and the [article](http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/) and [message board](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2935220) it links to.

My users **need** to be able to access our website using passwords. While the connection is established using SSL, we also want to provide any additional protection we can (even if they're futile) against malware in the user's machine/browser.

Are there any industry standards/best practices for client-side cryptography which help overcome any/all the limitations mentioned in the links above?

NOTE: When we finally chose a library, it was [jCryption](http://www.jcryption.org/) because it supported asymmetric encryption.

Comment: You can of course do client side crypto in JS, but you still won't get around the fundamental problems your second link talks about.

Comment: Am aware of that - hence the "even if they're futile" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Stanford Javascript Crypto Library (hosted http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/ on Stanford's server or here on GitHub) is a project by the Stanford Computer Security Lab to build a secure, powerful, fast, small, easy-to-use, cross-browser library for cryptography in Javascript.

Comment: Thank you. Will read up on this library further. Have already evaluated jCryption and thought it was good too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt to collate some possible standards:

1. Client-side cryptography must never be used as an alternative to SSL
2. Should ideally involve asymmetrical encryption (*it would be trivial to read the code and determine the key and reverse engineer otherwise*)